# In Magento 2.0 magento connect manager not found to change theme.

Tags: magento-2.0

I'm new with magento 2.0. In previous version of magento theme were changed using magento connect manager but in this version no such thing has found. please anybody tell me the alternate way of deploying new theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own theme in app/design/frontend/vendorname/yourthemename by inheriting magento2.0's luma or blanck theme. when you will create your theme you have to make regestration.php and theme.xml in your theme folder(just copy these both files from luma and change the names)

If you have purchased theme you can extract it in app/design/frontend and verify the regestration.php and theme.xml , after these you have to change current theme from admin dashbord->stores->configuration->general->design-> in this page change design theme name to your new theme name

finally you have to run bin/magento setup:upgrade